# freeradius, rlm_rest : Failed to Authenticate user

Tags: freeradius

I read : [Configuring rlm_rest module in FreeRadius](https://serverfault.com/questions/597393/configuring-rlm-rest-module-in-freeradius/799888#799888)

My FreeRadius version is 3.0.11 (git #d667a28)

My try is using included demo.pl, just change the port.

radtest --> radtest testing testing123 127.0.0.1 1 testing123

I tried some  scenario for 'authorize' section.

```
#authorize {
#    if (User-Password) {
#        update control {
#            Auth-Type := rest
#        }
#    }
#}

#authorize {
#    if (User-Password) {
#        update control {
#            Cleartext-Password := User-Password
#            Auth-Type := rest
#        }
#    }
#}

authorize {
    update control {
        Auth-Type := rest
    }
}
```

But I always got : 'Failed to authenticate the user'

Debug :

```
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: EXPAND /
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:    --> /
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Sending HTTP POST to "http://10.10.255.2:5000/"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Adding custom headers:
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   X-FreeRADIUS-Section: authenticate
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   X-FreeRADIUS-Server: default
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Request body content-type will be "application/json"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Encoding attribute "User-Name"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : string
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Length : 7
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Value  : "testing"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Encoding attribute "User-Password"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : string
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Length : 10
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Value  : "testing123"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Encoding attribute "NAS-IP-Address"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : ipaddr
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Length : 9
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Value  : "127.0.1.1"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Encoding attribute "NAS-Port"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : integer
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Length : 1
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Value  : 1
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Encoding attribute "Message-Authenticator"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : octets
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Length : 34
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Value  : "0x9d06a674fbd767958883955ee01ec1cb"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: JSON Data: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["testing"]},"User-Password":{"type":"string","value":["testing123"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["127.0.1.1"]},"NAS-Port":{"type":"integer","value":[1]},"Message-Authenticator":{"type":"octets","value":["0x9d06a674fbd767958883955ee01ec1cb"]}}
Tue Aug 30 03:54:46 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Returning 296 bytes of JSON data
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Processing response header
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Status : 200 (OK)
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : json (application/json)
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Parsing attribute "control:Cleartext-Password"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : string
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Length : 10
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Value  : "testing123"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: testing123
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: literal --> testing123
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: EXPAND testing123
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:    --> testing123
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Cleartext-Password := "testing123"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: FROM 1 TO 1 MAX 2
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: Examining Cleartext-Password
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: APPENDING Cleartext-Password FROM 0 TO 1
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: TO in 1 out 1
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: to[0] = Auth-Type
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Parsing attribute "reply:Reply-Message"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Type   : string
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Length : 18
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:   Value  : "Hello from demo.pl"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: Hello from demo.pl
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: literal --> Hello from demo.pl
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: EXPAND Hello from demo.pl
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest:    --> Hello from demo.pl
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: Reply-Message := "Hello from demo.pl"
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: FROM 1 TO 0 MAX 1
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: Examining Reply-Message
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: APPENDING Reply-Message FROM 0 TO 0
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) rest: ::: TO in 0 out 0
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: rlm_rest (rest): Released connection (0)
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0)     modsingle[authenticate]: returned from rest (rlm_rest) for request 0
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0)     [rest] = updated
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0)   } # authenticate = updated
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) Failed to authenticate the user
Tue Aug 30 03:54:47 2016 : Debug: (0) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
```

Could you please give me any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using rest to do authentication here, you're just using it to retrieve the user's password.

You need to list the pap module too to actually perform the comparison.

i.e.

```
authorize {
    rest
    pap
}

authenticate {
    pap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if authorize route is already authenticating the user, perhaps you could just set Auth-Type to Accept. It works for me, but I'm open to hear any drawbacks this has

```
#authorize {
#    if (User-Password) {
#        update control {
#            Auth-Type := Accept
#        }
#    }
#}
```